# Is there any way to get `find` not to quote the result of -printf

Tags: find

I want to use the `find` command with `-printf '%h\0'` to print the leading directories, separated by the nul character. Since I am using \0, I don't need, and don't want find to quote the results, as described in the "UNUSUAL FILENAMES" section of the find manpage.

Is there any way to tell find "I really know what I'm doing" and not do the quoting when using the `-printf` option?

Comment: Use `-print0` instead?

Comment: `-print0` includes the full path, I only want the directory that contains the file. And there isn't a `-printf0`

Comment: Can you show how to construct a sample tree, and the result you see when applying the command to that tree. Maybe also add what you'd like to see. The problem description is somewhat unclear (to me).

Comment: What are the research criterias? Could you simply : `find /some/path -type d -print0 | xargs -0 some_command_or_script`  ?

Comment: @U.Windl, try a filename with e.g. a newline or an ESC character. `find -printf` seems to display those as question marks (I tried on Ubuntu 22.04 with find 4.8.0), e.g. `touch $'new\nline.txt'; find . -name 'new*line*' -printf "%p\n"`. As far as I saw, it doesn't really "quote" them or do remotely the same GNU ls does, regardless of what the man page seems to imply.

Comment: Please show us an example of `-printf '%h\0'` adding quoting, including the version string of your copy of find and the true/exact name of the file being matched. I'm not sure I believe the claim that this actually occurs at all in the first place, and wonder if maybe you're looking at `set -x` output where xtrace operation is what's adding the quoting; a reproducer would clear up that kind of question.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, eh? Would the example above do? Yes, I used `%p`, but you can do it with `%h` too.

Comment: [`do_fprintf()` in `find/print.c`](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/findutils.git/tree/find/print.c?h=v4.9.0#n959) and the stuff in [`lib/printquoted.c`](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/findutils.git/tree/lib/printquoted.c?h=v4.9.0#n32) and [`lib/qmark.c`](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/findutils.git/tree/lib/qmark.c?h=v4.9.0#n106) look like the relevant parts.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy `mkdir $'\e' && touch $'\e'/foo && find $'\e' -printf '%h\0'` prints `.?` on my system.  `find (GNU findutils) 4.9.0`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Presumably you want to capture the output of `find` in a pipeline. In such instances the quoting is not enabled (it's only used for output to a terminal).

Example:

```
mkdir $'two line\ndirectory'
( cd two* && touch file )
```

Then,

```
find two* -printf '%h\n'

.
two line?directory
```

But,

```
find two* -printf '%h\n' | cat

.
two line
directory
```

This is explained in `man find` (GNU) in the section *UNUSUAL FILENAMES*:

> **`-printf`**, **`-fprintf`** If the output is not going to a terminal, it is printed as-is.

Otherwise (i.e. to a terminal),

> [...] The directives `%f`, `%h`, `%l`, `%p` and `%P` are quoted.

I should note that I have not been able to see a "quoted" file or directory name, despite what the documentation writes. I've only been able to see non-printing characters replaced with `?` per my example above.

Comment: doh. I misread that line as "If the output is going to a terminal, it is printed as-is".